# Windows 10 1903 - All programs except for Windows Store apps removed from Start menu and All Programs menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu, windows-10-v1903

When I upgraded from Windows 1809 to 1903 all of the programs in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` and `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` were removed from my Start menu and All Programs list, so that only apps installed through the Windows Store remain. From what I've searched this used to be an issue in Windows 7 and early versions of Windows 10 but I have not found anything more recent than 2017. To be clear, all the shortcuts are still in these folders, they just aren't showing in Start. Other people who I read about who had the similar issue had some shortcuts not showing from these folders, however, NONE of mine are showing. Shortcuts work fine everywhere else.

I have tried the advice I have found such as:

- Hiding and unhiding the start menu folders
- Running sfc /scannow and scan disk
- Removing shortcuts until there are less than 70 items in
  the start menu (apparently that used to be a bug)
- Restarting the computer many times
- Installing the latest windows updates
- Re-registering all the windows store apps (`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`)
- And since my appdata folder is on my D:\ drive I checked in the registry and the start menu is listed in the correct location.

I also tried pinning a programs to the start menu form the context menu on the desktop, however, it was pinned as a blank square with a complex file name (`W~{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Ardiuno` for instance), other programs pin in different formats. The formats seem to be:

- `W~{<STRING-OF-CHARACTERS>}\<NAME>`
- `W~<NAME>`
- `W~Microsoft.AutoGenerated.{<STRING-OF-CHARACTERS>}\<Name>`
- `W~D:\<PROGRAM-PATH>`

The last one is for programs installed on my D:\ drive.

My thoughts are that this is how I would expect Microsoft Store shortcuts to be formatted, but I don't really know what to try from there. It seems almost like Start has just stopped using the start menu directories.

Comment: Your issue is due to fact your AppData was on another partition other than your system partition.  I am actually shocked 1903 installed with your AppData configured to another partition

Comment: Why did you run a command to reinstall all UWP applications if your UWP applications were the only thing appearing in the Start Menu?

Comment: @Ramhound That could be the cause of the issue, however, 1803 and 1809 both installed successfully with AppData configured to my D:\ drive and everything else is using the AppData location successfully. I reinstalled the UWP applications because I didn't think it would hurt and I have had plenty of issues with windows fixed from doing something apparently unrelated.